# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POS

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Minha Blade

```
  <form action="{{route('Update.afiliados', $users->id)}}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @method('put') 
        <button  class="btn btn-block btn-flat btn-primary" method="post"> 
            <span class="fas fa-user-minus"></span>
            ATUALIZAR
        </button>
        </form>
  </form>
```

Meu Controller

```
public function update(Request $request)
{        if (!$users = users::find($id))
    {
        return redirect('Afiliados');
    }
    
    //$users = users::where('id', $id)->first();
     $users = users::findOrFail($request->id)->update($request->all());
     
    dd('TA OK');
}
```

minha rota

```
Route::put('/Afiliados/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\AfiliadosController::class, 'update'])->name('Update.afiliados');
```

Comment: Quando esse erro ocorre? Ao submeter o formulário? Qual a versão do laravel? São detalhes que ajudam responder a questão.

Answer (score -1):

O correto seria algo assim:
Blade

```
<form action="{{route('Update.afiliados', $users->id)}}" method="PUT">
  @csrf
           
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-flat btn-primary"> 
    <span class="fas fa-user-minus"></span>ATUALIZAR
  </button>
</form>
```

controller :

```
public function update(Request $request,$id){
}
```

Comment: Não existe method="PUT" usando via form de html, o correto é como ele fez usando `@method('put') `

Answer (score -1):

Olá!
Creio que ele esteja esperando o argumento ID, que você está passando mas não está identificada como dentro do form:

//Form

```
<form action="{{route('Update.afiliados', ['id' => $users->id])}}" method="POST">
    @method('put')      
    @csrf
```

//Controller

```
public function update(Request $request,$id){}
```

Considere usar as funções de rotas automatizadas do laravel, ele automaticamente cria as rotas e os controllers:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score -1):

O erro está aqui

```php
    if (!$users = users::find($id))
    {
        return redirect('Afiliados');
    }
```

Você não definiu o `$id` na método update, dessa forma o erro é lançado por que o navegador está tentando fazer `PUT` na rota que ele foi redirecionada aqui `redirect('Afiliados')`

Solução seria `public function update(Request $request, $id)` e evitar de redirecionar se não achar o cadastro, por que o navegador vai tentar fazer o PUT onde ele foi redirecionado, você pode evitar isso usando `users::findOrFail($id)`

Answer (score -2):

Se você estiver o usando mesmo route para aparecer a página vai dar esse erro. Você precisa de um route para aparecer a página e outro para enviar a atualização.

**Em route** você pode fazer isto:
//index seria a função para chamar a view que tem o formulário.
Route::get('/Afiliados/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\AfiliadosController::class, 'index']);

Route::put('/AfiliadosUpdate/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\AfiliadosController::class, 'update'])->name('Update.afiliados');